# Server Tag is not well formed - Error with Eval in ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, eval

I am having an issue with my Asp.NET app, in the HTML section, basically the issue comes from the EVAL value which is the "Id" properly, so I've tried using an RadioButton and Input, but any of them work properly.

This is my Asp.NET code.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="item">
            <input runat="server" id="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Nunca" type="radio" name="GrupID<%# Eval("Id") %>" value="Company" class="required">
            <label for="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Nunca">
                <img src="Content/img/seo_icon_1.svg" alt="">
                <strong>Nunca</strong>No, Nunca
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="item">
            <input runat="server" id="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Aveces" name="GrupID<%# Eval("Id") %>" type="radio" value="Private User" class="required">
            <label for="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Aveces">
                <img src="Content/img/seo_icon_2.svg" alt="">
                <strong>A veces</strong>Si, Algunas veces
            </label>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="item">
            <input runat="server" id="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Siempre" name="GrupID<%# Eval("Id") %>" type="radio" value="Private User" class="required">
            <label for="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Siempre">
                <img src="Content/img/seo_icon_3.svg" alt=""> 
                <strong>Siempre</strong>Si, Siempre
            </label>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the error:

Server Tag is not well formed.

I am not sure what's the issue, I have seen several similar questions, but no gives a real answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in ages, but it looks like you have the double quotes nested. Try changing some of them to single quotes.

Try

```
 <div class="item">
                <input runat="server" id="Radio1" type="radio" name='GrupID<%# Eval("Id") %>' value="Company" class="required"/>
                <label for="AnswerID<%# Eval("Id") %>_Nunca">
                    <img src="Content/img/seo_icon_1.svg" alt=""><strong>Nunca</strong>No, Nunca</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: I tried to preporduce it and the error goes away. You have to change it for the inputs though, you don't need to change it for the labels.

Comment: I changed my answer, please try again. Also it complained the input tags are not closed so I closed them.

Comment: I can see that the id says **Radio1**, I need to call all my inputs differently.

Comment: And capture the value of everyone of them. I am basically building a test app, so but I am trying to get it done but I've not had good results.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is going to work. You're trying to get it to dynamically bind a server control and the ID at the same time. It's not going to be able to predict the name and build the control tree effectively in that case. Your best bet may be avoid using the ID as a special name and use HTML data- attributes to store the specific values. Either that or do the complete control creation from the server side where you have control of the items before they are added to the control tree.